# nodejs windows exec promise pending

Tags: javascript, node.js, promise, exec

I am running `exec` to get id from computer hardware. I am trying to assign the id to the variable cpu_id so that i can use it later in my script in a http request param. When console log seems to always be outputting `Promise { <pending> }` instead of the captured id.

I have played around with wait and async but couldn't get things to operate the way they should. any help or pointers would be greatly appreciated.

```
function get_cpu_id() {
    if (process.platform === "win32") {
        return execShellCommand('wmic csproduct get UUID /format:list').then(function(std){
            return std.replace(/\s/g, '').split("=")[1];
        });
    } else {
        return execShellCommand('cat /proc/cpuinfo | grep Serial').then(function(std){
            return std;
        });
    }
}

function execShellCommand(cmd) {
    const exec = require('child_process').exec;

    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        exec(cmd, (error, stdout, stderr) => {
            if (error) {
                console.warn(error);
            }

            resolve(stdout ? stdout : stderr);
        });
    });
}

let cpu_id = get_cpu_id();

console.log(cpu_id);
```

Comment: `get_cpu_id` returns a Promise ... so `cpu_id` is a Promise ... try `get_cpu_id().then(cpu_id => console.log(cpu_id))`

Comment: by the way `.then(function(std){
            return std;
        })` is redundant do nothing code that you can get rid of

Comment: I have the then there for later purpose of parsing if i need to alter the serial id from unix devices.

Comment: @JaromandaX but how do i assign the value to the variable cpu_id so that I can use it later on in my script for ajax request?

Comment: For that, you'll need to learn how to use *asynchronous code* - there's plenty of questions on stack overflow with the same (impossible) requirement - so do some research - because **the** solution to the code you posted is what I suggested - but the code you *want* to use is different - so, you'll need to do some reserch

Comment: that is not the solution to the answer, as I stated i'm trying to assign it to a variable to use later on. thank you though.

Comment: It's how the code you've shown can console.log the result - so, as far as the code you've shown, it's correct - and that's why I put it as a comment, not an answer - because your code is simple to correct, but your requirement is unclear

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Exec returns a Promise.
Try using [`execSync`](https://nodejs.org/api/child_process.html#child_process_child_process_execsync_command_options):

```
const execSync = require('child_process').execSync;

function get_cpu_id() {
    if (process.platform === "win32") {
        return execSync('wmic csproduct get UUID /format:list').toString();
    } else {
        return execSync('cat /proc/cpuinfo | grep Serial').toString();
    }
}


let cpu_id = get_cpu_id();

console.log(cpu_id);
```